# xpages: trap when extension library widget container is closed

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have added a few widget containers (from the extension Library) to an app to display user's favorites, app specific content and a list of the most popular docs.

Although I managed to limit the number of items displayed in each widget container, I also wanted to keep the state of the various widgets containers in session scope variables, so the state of the various boxes could be passed along the other pages.  My problem is that ther eis no events that seem to trap the "close"/"open" action in a widget.

My question is: is that possible at all?  If os, how can I manage to achieve that?

As usual, thanks for the help

Code so far:

```
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="viewToolbox"
            viewName="ToolboxByProvLangDept">
            <xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(!!sessionScope.lang)  {
    sessionScope.lang;
} else {
    "FR";
}}]]></xp:this.categoryFilter>
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xe:widgetContainer id="widgetContainer1" titleBarText="Toolbox"
        style="padding-left:0.0px;padding-right:0.0px" collapsible="true">
        <xp:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{viewToolbox}" var="rowVar"
            rows="#{javascript:AppConfig.nbWidgetToolbox}">
            <xp:link escape="true" id="link1">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"/page.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=" + rowVar.getColumnValue("LinkUNID");
 }]]></xp:this.value>

                <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
    var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(rowVar.getColumnValue("LinkUNID"));
    return @LowerCase(doc.getItemValueString("Subject"));
} catch (e) {
    return "-subject unavailable-";
}}]]></xp:this.text>
            </xp:link>
            <hr />
        </xp:repeat>
    </xe:widgetContainer>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: I think you talk about "collapsed" state instead of "close", right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trap widget's open/closed status change on **client** side.

Add an **onclick** event on client side to open/close twist and initiate a partial refresh to an invisible panel "widgetStatus" which will write the current status "open" or "closed" to session scope variable with the id as name.

```xml
   <xp:eventHandler
      event="onClientLoad"
      submit="false">
      <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
           dojo.query(".lotusSection2").forEach(function(nodeWidget) {
               var id = nodeWidget.id;
               dojo.query(".lotusTwistyClosed", nodeWidget).forEach(function(node) {
                   dojo.connect(node, "onclick", function() { 
                       XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:widgetStatus}", {
                           params: {'status': 'open', 'id' : id}
                       });
                   });
               });
               dojo.query(".lotusTwistyOpen", nodeWidget).forEach(function(node) {
                   dojo.connect(node, "onclick", function() { 
                       XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:widgetStatus}", {
                           params: {'status': 'closed', 'id' : id}
                       });
                   });
               });
          });
      ]]>
      </xp:this.script>
   </xp:eventHandler>
   <xp:panel
      id="widgetStatus">
      <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            if (param.status) {
                sessionScope.put(param.id, param.status);
            }
            return true;
        }]]></xp:this.rendered>
   </xp:panel>
```

Then, you can calculate widget's "initClosed" attribute depending on session scope variable for widgetContainer's id:

```xml
<xe:widgetContainer id="widgetContainer1" titleBarText="Toolbox"
    style="padding-left:0.0px;padding-right:0.0px" collapsible="true"
    initClosed="#{javascript: 
         var status = sessionScope.get(getClientId(this.id));
         status ? status === 'closed' : false}">
```

It will be closed if the previous widget status was closed and it will be open if not.

This works for theme OneUI V3.0.2.

**Update**

This is a modified eventHandler version for themes OneUI V2.1 / OneUI V2.1 / OneUI V2 / OneUI:

```xml
   <xp:eventHandler
      event="onClientLoad"
      submit="false">
      <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
       dojo.query(".lotusWidget2").forEach(function(nodeWidget) {
            var id = nodeWidget.id;
            dojo.query(".lotusArrow", nodeWidget).forEach(function(node) {
                dojo.connect(node, "onclick", function() { 
                    XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:widgetStatus}", {
                        params: {'status': (node.id.match("_open$") ? 'closed' : 'open'), 'id' : id}
                    });
                });
            });
       });
      ]]></xp:this.script>
   </xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: Thanks Knut, but I already seea problem: I have 2 or 3 widgets on the page, so the dojo.query will go through all of them and save the status of the last widget in the sessionScope variable.

I will try to build on what you did to go through the various widgets and save each state in a different sessionScope variable.  I guess using dojo.query(".lotusWidget2") on top of the code you supplied will do the trick.

Comment: For some reason, the connect operation doen't seem to happen.  I added an alert just above the XSP.partial refresh line and it never shows up.  I did add the dojo._base.connect module as a resource...  Guess I'll have to figure out this one first before tackling the mutlipple widgets on the same page issue

Comment: I updated code so it will work for several widgets too. Every widgetContainer gets its own session scope variable with its id as name.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I might be missing something in order to get the dojo.connect to work???

No errors displayed, but the events don'T seem to get triggered.

Comment: the code is added as XSP.initSectionScript once rendered.  Should it be XSP.attachEvent???       Rendered code is -  

XSP.initSectionScript("view:_id1:_id2:LeftColumn:_id31:_id33:widgetContainer1_lk_close"...

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications to the code, as the widgets' IDs were different on some of the xpages used in the application.  I decided to use each widget's ID as the name of the scoped variable, so they would always be the same.

In order to acheive that, the first thing I changed was the widgetStatus panel.  The code of the panel now looks like this:

```
<xp:panel id="widgetStatus">
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (param.status) {
        var tmp = param.id.split(":");
        sessionScope.put(tmp[tmp.length-1], param.status);
}
return true;       }]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:label
            value="This cc contains the logic to keep the widgets' states in sessionScope variables."
            id="label1" rendered="false" style="color:rgb(255,0,0)">
        </xp:label>
    </xp:panel
```

I modifed the variable name saved in the sessionScope.

Second part of this change is the code used in the "initClosed" property of each widget, to see if it'S initially opened or closed.  Here is what the code now looks like:

```
var status = sessionScope.get(this.id);
status==='closed' ? true : false;
```

That way, if your widget's ID is widetPanel1, the session scope variable name will be widgetPanel1 and it will contain the state of the widget.

This little change works like a charm, even though the widgets' client ID changes for whatever reason.

Hope this will be helpful to others!  THanks again Knut, and I'll try to see if you do have an Amazon wish list  ;)

Comment: My pleasure :-) I'd recommend to delete your first answer as it's not helpful for understanding the solution anymore.